# How to know the detail of a bar graph without going to source table in Excel

Tags: excel

I was looking at one of my bar graph and thinking if there is a way to show the detail of a specific bar. To do this I have to go to the source sheet and apply filters to match with the excel condition, but i think it may exists an automatic way.

The source table has this structure:

```
MONTH CATEGORY DESCRIPTION AMOUNT 
feb16    A       LALAL      $ 100
feb16    B       LELEL      $ 200
feb16    B       KKKKK      $ 50
mar16    A       KKKKK      $ 90
mar16    A       SSSSS      $ 100
mar16    B       DDDDD      $ 500
```

In another sheet I have a table who compute automatically the total amount of each CATEGORY of the month indicated, for example:

```
MONTH: mar16
CATEGORY  TOTAL AMOUNT
    A       $ 190
    B       $ 500
```

The category are always statics in this table. Well, this table has a bar graph at the right with CATEGORY/TOTAL AMOUNT relation. What i want to do (or similar thing if you know) when i pass the mouse pointer over a bar i want a popup (like the comment) to show the detail of that bar. Continuing the previous example, if i put the mouse over "A" category bar, i want the popup displaying the detail (as simple text, obviously):

```
mar16    A       KKKKK      $ 90
mar16    A       SSSSS      $ 100
```

Regards!

Comment: AFAIK, Excel does not have a hover event that would trigger this. Have you considered pivot tables/pivot charts for some of your solutions?

Comment: @teylyn No, I did not consider that. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Use a pivot table and a pivot chart. Group the pivot table by category and date. Drill into the pivot table groups. The chart will reflect the drill-down level of the pivot table.

For a more elegant approach try out Power View (Excel 2013 and later), where you can drill into the chart, or go really wild and use Power BI.